# Overriding spaceship operator when parent class does not define spaceship operator for itself

Tags: c++, overriding, language-lawyer, spaceship-operator

The following code is treated differently by the compilers:

```
#include <compare>

struct A;

struct I {
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A&) const { 
        return std::strong_ordering::equal; 
    }
};

struct A : I {
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A&) const = default;
};
```

Both GCC and MSVC accept it, but not Clang which returns the error:

```
warning: explicitly defaulted three-way comparison operator is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A&) const = default;
defaulted 'operator<=>' is implicitly deleted because there is no viable three-way comparison function for base class 'I'
error: deleted function 'operator<=>' cannot override a non-deleted function
    virtual std::strong_ordering operator <=>(const A&) const = default;
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WGrGTe89z

It seems that Clang is the only one right here, since `I::operator <=>(const I&) const` is not defined, so `A::operator <=>(const A&) const` must be implicitly deleted, and a deleted method cannot override a not deleted method from `I`. Are the other compilers also within their rights to accept the code?

Comment: virtual comparison operators are a minefield

Answer (score 2):

The other compilers will also reject the code once you write something like `A a; a < a;`, which makes me think Clang is rejecting it prematurely. In [[class.compare.default]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.compare#default-1), the standard says:

> A comparison operator function for class C that is defaulted on its first declaration and is not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used or needed for constant evaluation.
> Name lookups in the defaulted definition of a comparison operator function are performed from a context equivalent to its function-body.
> A definition of a comparison operator as defaulted that appears in a class shall be the first declaration of that function.

Since there is no expression resolving to `A::operator<=>(const A&)` in your example, no definition is needed and it should not be rejected, even if the function would always end up being deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the other compilers also implicitly delete `A::operator <=>(const A&) const`, but it shall be a compilation error since the method with such signature is virtual from the base class and cannot be deleted in the child class. This leads the other compilers to incorrectly fail at link time (GCC) or produce invalid code (MSVC), demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cfsa3ncq6

Comment: @Fedor: Three different results! What a mess. That demo code is quite smelly and I can see how Clang wants to keep you from hanging yourself. However, I don't think `(i <=> a)` is odr-using `A::operator<=>(const A&)`, so the standard probably doesn't require even a warning for this kind of deviousness.

Comment: I reported GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103689